# touch issue advice

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch

Hi guys i have a issue with my code.
I have 6 sprites that moves from bottom and to the top. 3 of the sprites can be touched. When i touch that sprite counter will increate +1 and that sprite will be removed.
The problem I'm facing is that when i select that sprite the counter increase to 1, but if i select that sprite twice within half secs, counter increase to 2.
i can see on the first touch the sprite disappear, but why once it disappears it can still detect that sprite bounding box(if click within half sec).

How can i solve this problem?
I'm using cocos2d

P.S if i select the sprite after half sec no problem.

```
//other code

CGPoint gridu2 =ccp(80,-45);
CGPoint gridu3 =ccp(80,-130);
CGPoint gridu4 =ccp(80,-215);
CGPoint gridu7 =ccp(240,-45);
CGPoint gridu8 =ccp(240,-130);
CGPoint gridu9 =ccp(240,-215);

//left grid up
id actionMoveUp2 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:7 position:ccp(80,winSize.height + 215)];
id actionMoveUp3 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:7 position:ccp(80,winSize.height + 130)];
id actionMoveUp4 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:7 position:ccp(80,winSize.height + 45)];

//right grid down
id actionMoveDown7 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:7 position:ccp(240,winSize.height +255)];
id actionMoveDown8 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:7 position:ccp(240,winSize.height +170)];
id actionMoveDown9 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:7 position:ccp(240,winSize.height +85)];

correctColor1.position=gridu2;
correctColor2.position=gridu3;
correctColor3.position=gridu9;
random4.position=gridu4;
random5.position=gridu7;
random6.position=gridu8;

[correctColor1 runAction:actionMoveUp2];
[correctColor2 runAction:actionMoveUp3];
[correctColor3 runAction:actionMoveDown9];
[random4 runAction:actionMoveUp4];
[random5 runAction:actionMoveDown7];
[random6 runAction:actionMoveDown8];

[self addChild:correctColor1 z:10 tag:1];
[self addChild:correctColor2 z:10 tag:2];
[self addChild:correctColor3 z:10 tag:3];
[self addChild:random4 z:1 tag:14];
[self addChild:random5 z:1 tag:15];
[self addChild:random6 z:1 tag:16];

-(void)addToScore:(int)number
{
score=score+number;
[scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score]];
}

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
CGSize winSize =[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
UITouch* myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView: [myTouch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

// to remove touched sprite
int totalNumberOfItems=3;
for (int y=1; y < totalNumberOfItems; y++){
    CCSprite *temp = (CCSprite*)[self getChildByTag:y];

    CGRect correctColor = [temp boundingBox];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(correctColor, location)) {
        NSLog(@"touched");
        [self removeChild:temp cleanup:YES ];
        [self addToScore:1];
        return;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to implement a ccTouchEnded function so that you can detect the touch has ended and avoid the duplicate touches.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could try. Try putting the `[self removeChild:temp cleanup:YES]` in the `ccTouchesEnded:` method. Im not sure that would work.

Another thing you could do is disable touch for half a second. Call `[self setIsTouchEnabled:NO]` and then set it to yes after a delay in `ccTouchesEnded:`

Hope this helps

Comment: i found another solution. i have used i added `    NSUInteger tapCount = [myTouch tapCount];
    if (tapCount == 1)`

Comment: ya thats easier to do.. does it work if you keep your finger down instead of tapping?